# Element wise mean from data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns and 16 rows. Each element has values like row1 values are (0.9, 0.9, 1.0), (0.7,0.9, 1.0), (0.9, 0.9, 1.0). I want element wise mean e.g., (0.9+0.7+0.9/3), (0.9+0.9+0.9/3), (1.0+1.0+1.0/3) and store the result as new column. Any suggestions?

```
      SHO1          SHO2             SHO3
1  0.7, 0.9, 1.0   0.9, 0.9, 1.0   0.7, 0.9, 1.0
2  0.7, 0.9, 1.0   0.9, 0.9, 1.0   0.7, 0.9, 1.0
3  0.0, 0.0, 0.1   0.9, 0.9, 1.0   0.0, 0.0, 0.1
```

expected out for row1:

```
0.7+0.9+0.7/3, 0.9+0.9+0.9/3, 1.0+1.0+1.0/3
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your data in a proper format?  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: We will need a `dput` of your data. Also, I think you are missing a parenthesis in each of these statements such as `(0.7+0.9+0.7)/3`

Comment: Its giving an error

"Error in strsplit(x, ", ") : non-character argument "

Comment: It is because you have factor variable.  Try `strsplit(as.character(x), ', '`

Comment: My dear akrun, thanks for your help and sorry if i offended you. I think i am unable to explain my question but I really appreciate your help. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: As I already said, please provide `dput` of your data and your exact desired output.

Comment: It's okay.  Just now I checked your previous questions.  All of them were not so clear.  In [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809839/reading-columns-and-assigning-values-within-r) I suggested to update your question with the example I created and the expected result.  But, it seems that you were not interested in doing that.  So, I am thinking that you were asking questions just for fun.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: here is dput of first four rows...

structure(list(SHO1 = structure(list(VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1), VH = c(0.9, 
0.9, 1), M = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7), H = c(0.7, 0.9, 1)), .Names = c("VH", 
"VH", "M", "H")), SHO2 = structure(list(H = c(0.7, 0.9, 1), H = c(0.7, 
0.9, 1), H = c(0.7, 0.9, 1), VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1)), .Names = c("H", 
"H", "H", "VH")), SHO3 = structure(list(VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1), 
    VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1), M = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7), VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 
    1)), .Names = c("VH", "VH", "M", "VH"))), .Names = c("SHO1", 
"SHO2", "SHO3"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: first row contains c(0.9, 0.9, 1.0) of SHO1 as first element c(0.7,0.9,1.0) of SHO2 as 2nd element and c(0.9,0.9,1.0) of SHO3 as 3rd element... my expected output should be a new column 0.9+0.7+0.9/3, 0.9+0.9+0.9/3, 1.0+1.0+1.0/3 .... i.e., taking the mean of these vectors element by element....

I hope i have explained the question well

Comment: Based on the dput output, you have `list` as each column of the dataset.  `m1 <- Reduce('+', lapply(df1, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))/ncol(df1);df1$newCol <-  do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(m1), sep=", "))` or you can have a `list` as the new column i.e. `df1$newCol <- split(m1, row(m1))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `dput` output by the OP (in the comments), we found that the columns in 'df1' are not 'strings'.  Infact each element of each column is a `list`.  So, instead of doing `strsplit` (as I suggested earlier), we loop through the columns with `lapply` and `rbind` the `list` elements (`do.call(rbind`). The output 'list' contains 'matrix' as list elements.
 We can use `Reduce` to take the elementwise sum (`Reduce('+', ..`), and divide by the length of the `list` i.e. 3.

The matrix output ('m1') can be pasted together rowwise (`do.call(paste`) after converting to 'data.frame' and create a new column in the original dataset ('df1').

```
m1 <- Reduce('+', lapply(df1, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))/ncol(df1)
df1$newCol <- do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(m1), sep=", "))
df1
#           SHO1          SHO2          SHO3
#1 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.9, 0.9, 1.0
#2 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.9, 0.9, 1.0
#3 0.3, 0.5, 0.7 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.3, 0.5, 0.7
#4 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.9, 0.9, 1.0
#                                     newCol
#1                 0.833333333333333, 0.9, 1
#2                 0.833333333333333, 0.9, 1
#3 0.433333333333333, 0.633333333333333, 0.8
#4                 0.833333333333333, 0.9, 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(SHO1 = structure(list(VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1), 
VH = c(0.9, 
0.9, 1), M = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7), H = c(0.7, 0.9, 1)), .Names = c("VH", 
"VH", "M", "H")), SHO2 = structure(list(H = c(0.7, 0.9, 1), H = c(0.7, 
0.9, 1), H = c(0.7, 0.9, 1), VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1)), .Names = c("H", 
"H", "H", "VH")), SHO3 = structure(list(VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1), 
VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 1), M = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7), VH = c(0.9, 0.9, 
1)), .Names = c("VH", "VH", "M", "VH"))), .Names = c("SHO1", 
"SHO2", "SHO3"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks for help but my output is like this:
   SHO1          SHO2          SHO3              TFN
1  0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 NA, 0.9, NA
2  0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 NA, 0.9, NA
3  0.0, 0.0, 0.1 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.0, 0.0, 0.1 NA, 0.3, NA
4  0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 NA, 0.9, NA
5  0.9, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 0.7, 0.9, 1.0 NA, 0.9, NA

for new column element 1 and 3 are not giving results instead NA while element 2 is right. I am trying to figure this out.